# Why doesn't this clause have perfect tense?

Tags: tense, conjunctions

> Harry watched Hagrid getting redder and redder in the face **as he
>   called for more wine**, finally kissing Professor McGonagall on the
>   cheek, who, to Harry's amazement, giggled and blushed, her top hat
>   lopsided.  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

What does the bold-faced part mean? If it is the reason for Hagrid’s getting redder, I guess its tense needs to be perfect one: as he had called for more wine.

Comment: I think you are understanding *as* to mean *because*; but here it means *while*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sentence is perfectly fine, and it is similar to the following ones.

> President Obama **launched** a pre-emptive attack against it as he **called** for federal immigration reform.

> Alabama Governor Bob Riley **was joined** by Beth and Jug Twitty today, as he **called** for a boycott of travel to Aruba.

> The crowd **roared** as he **called** for cutting defense to pay for domestic programs.

*As* is used to *show* the contemporaneity of two actions: The crowd roared when he called for a cutting defense, and Hagrid got redder when he drank more wine. In such a case, I would not use two different tenses; if I use the Simple Past with a clause, I will use the Simple Past also with the clause starting with *as*.

Answer (score 1):

As he called for more wine = as he drank more wine.

The sentence works as is because it is relaying the passage of time instead of stating a cause and effect.